How to fix frame drops in Unity
I'm Korean, so please understand if there are any strange grammar. This project I created was a rhythm game and used the bpm system.
However, sometimes notes are created slowly. I think frame drops are the problem, how can I fix it?

Unfortunately it's impossible to help without more detail. Have you tried the Unity profiler to see what might be causing those hitches?

Without knowing anything about your game and how it works all I can say is use the profiler to figure out if your frame rate is inconsistent and what is happening during any long frames. If you are creating a lot of temporary objects leading to issues with garbage collection do some research into object pooling so you can recycle them instead.

There is no magic answer to game optimization, the answer is you need to do a million things that are specific to your game. The only general advice is to use the profiler to determine if you even actually have a performance issue and if so then where, and then apply the creative part of your programmer brain to optimize that part of the code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Is your problem solved? Can you provide a minimal sample?

as other comments said there is no general answer first you need to profile your game to see what is slowing your game down.
this is some general advices and this is somehow in depth article about it that may help you (in addition explained how to use profiler and analyze it).
